# DLL load failed error in pytest using pycharm. Works fine in Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using a Windows machine with Anaconda on it. I've installed numpy on the base environment using conda. When I run a test using `pytest` on PyCharm, I get an error. However, when I run the same on Anaconda prompt (using the same interpreter), I get no errors.

`pytest` runs fine on Anaconda prompt:

[image: pytest runs fine on Anaconda Prompt]

`pytest` on PyCharm gives this error:

[image: pytest on PyCharm gives this error]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thank you for including images, but can you [edit] your question and include the error directly? Text is searchable, images are not. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Install latest PyCharm 2019.1.3. It contains a bunch of relevant fixes (e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35141).